# jquery top.document or not?

Tags: jquery

I have a page called loader.html. It contains an iframe, which contains jQuery.

On index.html, I do `<iframe src="loader.html">`

How do I access the elements inside loader.html ? top.document ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`contents()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contents):

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body');
```